# Prolog Member Predicate Weight per Item

Tags: list, prolog, member

I'm putting together this rule for my prolog program that when called should list the number of toppings each can be contained. It cannot go below or above 40

```
pizza(P, S, B, O, M) :-
    member(P, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]),
    member(S, [0,1,2,3,4]),
    member(B, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    member(O, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),
    member(M, [0,1,2,3,4,5]),
    X is 4*P + 10*s + 6*B + 5*O + 7*M,
    X =< 40,
    Y is 40-X.
```

It keeps on producing this error.

> ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `s/0' is not a function

when I try to use the call to the function `pizza(1, S, 1, O, M).`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that

```
X is 4*P + 10*s + 6*B + 5*O + 7*M,
```

should be written as

```
X is 4*P + 10*S + 6*B + 5*O + 7*M,
```

I mean: an uppercase `S` instead a lowercase `s`.